# How to equally align three figures in two-column IEEE format

Tags: floats, overleaf

I am working in [Overleaf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overleaf) using the IEEE two-column format. Why are my first two figures too close, but the second and third have huge space?

[image: Example]

The code is this

```
\begin{figure*}
 \begin{minipage}[t]{.31\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}%
        \caption{eeee} \label{ssss}
  \end{minipage}\hfil
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.31\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{{example-image-a}}
\caption{bbbbbbb} \label{xx}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.31\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{{example-image-a}}
\caption{aaaaaaaaa} \label{dd}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure*}
```

Comment: Can you please add the missing code parts, so we can copy and compile right away, and see your problem? // It may be even good to include some blindtext and a screenshot of your current result.

Comment: between minipages suppose to be `\hfill`, not `\hfil` ...

Answer (score 4):

In your code fragment you have typing error, I guess. I marked it by `% <---`:

```
\begin{figure*}
 \begin{minipage}[t]{.31\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}%
        \caption{eeee} \label{ssss}
  \end{minipage}\hfil                 % <--- probably should be \hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.31\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{{example-image-a}}
\caption{bbbbbbb} \label{xx}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.31\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{{example-image-a}}
\caption{aaaaaaaaa} \label{dd}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure*}
```

[image]

- or you may like to have defined both distances between `minipage`s determined by `\hfil` and content of `figure*` centered:

```
\begin{figure*}
\centering
 \begin{minipage}[t]{.31\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}%
        \caption{eeee} \label{ssss}
  \end{minipage}\hfil
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.31\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{{example-image-a}}
\caption{bbbbbbb} \label{xx}
\end{minipage}\hfil
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.31\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{{example-image-a}}
\caption{aaaaaaaaa} \label{dd}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure*}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to `minipage`s, you could load the `subfig` package and use `\subfloat[]{}` in order to have more control over formatting and spacing of the main caption and sub-captions.

[image]

As a side note, `\stretch{n}` allows for unequal but controlled image distribution, in case you would like to keep some images closer to each other. For instance, using `\stretch{1}` and `\stretch{3}` gives the following effect

[image]

If the same `\stretch` is applied between figures, it works exactly like `\hfill`.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}   % For dummy text

%%% Settings for subfigures
% If lofdepth=2, LoF will also contain sub-figures
%\captionsetup{lofdepth=1}
% Position and format of the main caption
\captionsetup[figure]{position=bottom,skip=12pt}
% Position and format of sub-captions
\captionsetup[subfigure]{font=small,position=bottom,captionskip=6pt}   


\begin{document}
\section{The first section}
\kant[1-4]   % Dummy text

\begin{figure*}
  \centering
  \subfloat[The left]{%
    \label{subfig:three-images-a}%
    \includegraphics[width=0.28\textwidth,height=2.3cm]{example-image-a}}%
  \hspace{\stretch{1}}%
  \subfloat[The middle]{%
    \label{subfig:three-images-b}%
    \includegraphics[width=0.28\textwidth,height=2.8cm]{example-image-b}}%
  \hspace{\stretch{1}}%
  \subfloat[The right]{%
    \label{subfig:three-images-c}%
    \includegraphics[width=0.28\textwidth,height=2.5cm]{example-image-c}}%
  \caption{Three images}\label{fig:three-images}
\end{figure*}

\section{The other section}
\kant[5-7]   % Dummy text

References:   % Demonstrates referencing to sub-figures
\begin{itemize}
  \item[] the left image: \cref{fig:three-images}~\subref{subfig:three-images-a}
  \item[] the right image: \cref{fig:three-images}~\subref{subfig:three-images-c}
  \item[] the middle image: \cref{fig:three-images}~\subref{subfig:three-images-b}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```